# Google Calendar Access Permissions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to create a script with Google Apps Script that will allow me to to determine if the specific calendar is set to public or not.

I found the following in the Advanced Calendar Services documentation that Lists the calendars shown in the user's calendar list.  Even if I simply log the variable calendars, I am not seeing any information that tells me whether or not the calendar is set to public or not.

```
function listCalendars() {
  var calendars;
  var pageToken;
  do {
    calendars = Calendar.CalendarList.list({
    maxResults: 100,
    pageToken: pageToken,
  });
  if (calendars.items && calendars.items.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < calendars.items.length; i++) {
      var calendar = calendars.items[i];
      Logger.log('%s (ID: %s)', calendar.summary, calendar.id);
  }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No calendars found.');
  }
   pageToken = calendars.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
}
```

My goal is to simply return whether or not the calendar is set to public or not.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to know if a calendar is public or not would be to try to access the calendar using an api key if its public you will get info back if not you will get a no access error message.

If you dont like error messages then you can take the request you have now and loop though each of your calendars requesting the

[Acl: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/acl/list)

this response contains a list of resources

```
{
  "kind": "calendar#aclRule",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": string,
  "scope": {
    "type": string,
    "value": string
  },
  "role": string
}
```

Scope will tell you what type of calendar it is if its default (public) or a user, group or domain calendar.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  This should get me started.